# Flatten lists in map into single list

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I have defined a `map` like below and it has lists of strings as values

```
Map<Integer,List<String>> MapOf_words_arrays = new HashMap<Integer,List<String>>();
```

I need to get the values of above Map in to one string array  (e.g shown below) , .

```
["dog","cat"]
["book","pen","phone","waterbottle"]
.
.
.etc
```

I'm using the below statement

```
String wordlists = MapOf_words_arrays.values().toArray(new String[0]);
```

but I'm getting an error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException:
>   java.util.ArrayList$SubList
>           at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(AbstractCollection.java:196)
>           at ScrapePages.main(ScrapePages.java:98)

Can anybody help me out here?

Comment: I need food to survive, but I don't expect someone to give it to me upon request without paying them first (you need to ask a question before we can answer it).

Comment: ok.. and whats stopping you to achieve that?

Comment: Example is given here : https://dzone.com/articles/hashmap-%E2%80%93-single-key-and

Comment: Something like: `MapOf_words_arrays.valueSet().toString().replace("],", "]\r\n")`.

Comment: @byxor , Thanks for your feed back. and I have Improved my problem there.

Comment: Please stick to **naming conventions**, variable names always start with a **lower case** character. So it would be `mapOf_words_arrays` instead. Also, most Java devs would rather write `mapOfWordsArrays` and don't use *underscore* (except for constants).

Comment: @Zabuza, Thanks for you valuable feed back!!

Answer (score 5):

### Explanation

`ArrayStoreException` means that you are trying to store the **wrong type** of elements into the wrong type of array (see its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html)).

You are calling

```
values().toArray(new String[0])
```

So you try to store something into an array which accepts `String` as its elements. However `Map#values` doesn't return `String` in your case, it returns a `Collection` containing elements of type `List<String>`. That's why it wants an array of type `List`, not `String`.

---

### Solution

You first need to *flatten* all sub-lists into one. For this you have multiple options. The most straight-forward solution would be to **iterate all elements** and then **add them into** another `List`, then **convert** this list into an **array**:

```
List<String> valuesFlatten = new ArrayList<>();

// Flatten all values
for (List<String> valueContainer : MapOf_words_arrays.values()) {
    valuesFlatten.addAll(valueContainer);
}

// Create and fill the array
String[] result = new String[valuesFlatte.size()];
valuesFlatten.toArray(result);
```

---

Or more compact, a solution using `Stream`s (**Java 8**):

```
String[] result = MapOf_words_arrays.values().stream()  // List<String>
    .flatMap(List::stream)                              // String
    .toArray(String[]::new)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by creating a **Iterator** from the map values. Then iterate through all values using the while loop and get all Strings from the lists and add them to a single **ArrayList** and convert it to String[]. :)

**Here is working the code:**

```
Map<Integer,List<String>> MapOf_words_arrays = new HashMap<Integer,List<String>>();
Iterator<List<String>> iterator = MapOf_words_arrays.values().iterator();

ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> tempList;
while(iterator.hasNext()){

    tempList = iterator.next();
    for(String item: tempList){
        data.add(item);
    }

}

// Here is your array with all strings.
String[] array = data.toArray(new String[]{});
```

Comment: Well done. However there is no need for the extra `Iterator`. You can instead use the **enhanced for loop** (*for-each loop*), it'll do the same behind the scenes but looks more compact.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ArrayList<String> allStrings = new ArrayList<>();
for (List<String> list : MapOf_words_arrays.values()) {
    allStrings.addAll(list);
}
String[] stringArray = allStrings.toArray(new String[] {});  //The array you wanted
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can convert `Map<Integer, List<String>>` to either `List<String>` or `String[]`.

**NOTE:** at the end, checkout out the simplest way to convert it using `Java 8 Streams`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MapClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
        map.put(1, Arrays.asList("11", "12", "13"));
        map.put(2, Arrays.asList("21", "22", "23"));
        // if you need list
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (List<String> list : map.values()) {
            result.addAll(list);
        }
        System.out.println(result);

        // if you need array
        String[] array = result.toArray(new String[0]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

        // using streams
        List<String> java8List = map
                                .values()
                                .stream()
                                .flatMap(l -> l.stream())
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(java8List);

        // if you need array
        String[] arrays = java8List.toArray(new String[0]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrays));
    }
}
```

Sample Run:

```
[11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23]
[11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23]
[11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23]
[11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23]
```

Comment: You can use method references instead of lambda: `List::stream` instead of `l -> l.stream()`. You can also directly collect into an array from a `Stream` if you want with `Stream#toArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full working demo of what you wanted

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {

        Map<Integer,List<String>> MapOf_words_arrays = new HashMap<Integer,List<String>>();

        ArrayList<String> s1=new ArrayList<>();
        s1.add("anupam");
        s1.add("lucky");

        ArrayList<String> s2=new ArrayList<>();
        s2.add("anu");
        s2.add("luck");

        MapOf_words_arrays.put(0,s1);
        MapOf_words_arrays.put(1,s2);

        ArrayList<String> final_ans=new ArrayList<String>();

        for(List<String> list : MapOf_words_arrays.values())
        {
            for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
            {
                final_ans.add(list.get(i));
            }
        }

        String[] myArray = final_ans.toArray(new String[final_ans.size()]);


        for(int b=0;b<myArray.length;b++)
            System.out.print(myArray[b]+" ");



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider an elegant Java 8 solution, if you can.

```
// compute the size of the target array
int size = map.values().stream().reduce(0,(k, l) -> k+l.size(), (l,r) ->l+r);
// allocate the target array
String[] test = new String[size];
// reduce the map to a list (this is in general more efficient than directly reducing it to an array)
map.values().stream().reduce(
    new ArrayList<String>(),
    (l, x) -> {l.addAll(x); return l;}
    ).toArray(test);

// test output that everything worked        
for (String s:test)
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Or **flatten** all sub-lists using `Stream#flatMap` and then just collect it as array with `Stream#toArray`. Your code looks a bit hard to read, especially the size-computation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with Java 8 features (but without the overhead of streams):

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
mapOfWordsArrays.values().forEach(result::addAll);
```

This iterates over all the values of the map, and adds each value (which is of type `List<String>`) to the `result` list. This is why I'm using the `List.addAll` method.

Another way would be to iterate directly on the entries of the map:

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
mapOfWordsArrays.forEach((k, v) -> result.addAll(v));
```

IMO, this is the most compact, yet readable and easiest way.

I suggest you check the docs of [`List.addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-), [`Iterable.forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) and [`Map.forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) methods for further details.

Note: I've changed the variables names to stick to Java naming conventions.